# How can I add a number to my morris.js donut chart legend?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach, morris.js

I have several `morris.js` charts that populate from my databases depending on certain search terms. Im using the following code to build a "Legend" for my donut charts. The code works fine but Im struggling with adding both a number and text, I'm getting a console error:

> ReferenceError: value not defined

Here is the code I'm currently using (works great):

```
// Build the Donut:
var donut = Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donut',
    data   : donutParts,
    colors: color_array
});
// Build the Legend:
donut.options.data.forEach(function(label, i){
    var legendItem = $('<span></span>').text(label['label']).prepend('<i>&nbsp;</i>');
    legendItem.find('i').css('backgroundColor', donut.options.colors[i]);
    $('#legend').append(legendItem)
})
```

This will give me a legend with matching color squares with the appropriate labels eg:

```
[red] UK
```

But I want:

```
[red] # UK
```

I've tried using `.integer` and other variations like so:

```
// Build the Donut:
var donut = Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donut',
    data   : donutParts,
    colors: color_array
});
// Build the Legend:
donut.options.data.forEach(function(label, i){
    var legendItem = $('<span></span>').text(label['label']).integer(['value']).prepend('<i>&nbsp;</i>');
    legendItem.find('i').css('backgroundColor', donut.options.colors[i]);
    $('#legend').append(legendItem)
})
```

But this gives me the error that value is not defined, i want to take the `value(v)` from `donutParts`

Here is my donutParts variable:

```
// Fetch the data to populate the donut chart:
var chartData = JSON.parse( $('#chartData').val() );

// Break up the object into parts of the donut:
var donutParts = [];
$.each( chartData, function(k,v){
    donutParts.push({
        label: k,
        value: v
    });
});
```

Any help? cheers!

**ANSWER**

The following code produces the desired output:

```
// Build the Legend:
    donut.options.data.forEach(function(label, i){
    var legendItem = $('<span></span>').text(label['value']+" "+label['label']).prepend('<i>&nbsp;</i>');
    legendItem.find('i').css('backgroundColor', donut.options.colors[i]);
    $('#legend').append(legendItem)
    })
```

This is a SS of the legend output after implementing the given answer
[image: https://ibb.co/cYMCbk]

Big thank you to @WillParky93

Comment: The code you are using is basicly saying `"Get something within <span></span> that has label of "label" then add at the end of it some <i> tags. Once added the <i> tags, attach a background colour to it"`  So with this in mind, what you are attempting to do with .integer(['value']) doesnt make sense. I'm not that good at jquery but I'll give it a crack. What is the value you are trying to assign this?

Comment: Im also not that great with jquery, I intend to take a few courses haha, thanks for answering though, I'll add my donutParts variable to my question

Comment: also my i tags are at the front of each label and styled using css :) the legend works but I cant get a number. Not really needed but it would be a nice touch

Comment: Could you post (in the OP) the output of one of those elements please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I said in the comments was technically wrong but after further reading this is what the 'donut.options.data.forEach' is doing.

Create an object dom of `<span></span>` -> add the text from label['label'] (which appears to be UK in your example) -> add some `<i>` tags.
THEN
Find the newly created  tags -> add the CSS rule for background colour
THEN
add it to your #legend

So the solution was actually more simple when thinking of it like this; the answer  be just this:

```
    // Build the Legend:
    donut.options.data.forEach(function(label, i){
    var legendItem = $('<span></span>').text(label['value']+" "+label['label']).prepend('<i>&nbsp;</i>');
    legendItem.find('i').css('backgroundColor', donut.options.colors[i]);
    $('#legend').append(legendItem)
    })
```

The change is in `.text(label['label'])` which is now `.text(label['value']+" "+label['label'])`